# Python, Windows: Create a process on a specific NUMA node with core mask

Tags: python, winapi, process, affinity, numa

I'm required to run processes with a given NUMA node and core mask, (like in the cmd command: "start").
Unfortunately, the `subprocess` module doesn't support that (at least not that I know of).

Also, on my task-manager I can see that there are 72 logical processors. The `psutil` function `cpu_count` returns 32. I can't figure out why. Also, there is no way to tell how many NUMA nodes there are.

I know I can create a process with the windows api. But how can I see how many NUMA nodes I have, and how many cores in each NUMA node? If you know a another way except the windows api, that would also be great. If it can't be done in python, I don't mind doing it with C++.

One more thing - I know I can use `subprocess.Popen("cmd /C start <application>")` but then I won't have the application's process object, just the cmd process object. So I don't want that option.

Thank you so much!

Comment: need use [UpdateProcThreadAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686880(v=vs.85).aspx) with `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PREFERRED_NODE` - "This attribute specifies a preferred NUMA node for the new process and causes Windows to assign the new process to the group that contains the specified node, assuming that it is a valid node and contains processors. The process affinity is set to all logical processors in the node’s group, including any processors that belong to other nodes"

Comment: [GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405488(v=vs.85).aspx) - give you full info about NUMA nodes

Comment: Thanks! I was actually pretty close. I tried using the [GetLogicalProcessorInformation function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194(v=vs.85).aspx) and in the example on that page, they calculated the numa node count, and I got 1 (expected 2).
I'll try using the `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx`. Maybe it will work. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to do this in a 64 bit process I think. All the support for large machines, machines with > 64 processors, processor groups, and so on is available only under 64 bit. I'll bet that's a confounding issue for you. A cpu count of 32 smacks very much of a 32 bit process!

Comment: this is new api. pointer to `NUMA_NODE_RELATIONSHIP.NodeNumber` you need use with `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PREFERRED_NODE` - count of logical processors in node - this count of non zero bits in `NUMA_NODE_RELATIONSHIP.GroupMask.Mask`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653313(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194(v=vs.85).aspx) - "Returns the logical processor information (package, cache, NUMA, and so on) of processors **in the group to which the calling thread** is currently assigned." - so this is group relative info

Comment: OK thank you very much for all of your answers! I guess I have a lot to learn on that subject...

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty daunting subject, even if you are working directly with the API. If you are trying to do it from Python then it could be even trickier.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I guess I'll do it with C++ then.